# Group dates by only month and year

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table like the following:

```
id | assignment | duedate
1  | Math       | 2012-01-01
2  | History    | 2012-02-02
3  | Science    | 2012-01-01
4  | Government | 2012-02-01
5  | Government | 2013-01-13
6  | History    | 2013-03-13
```

Is it possible to make some sql query such that I get a grouping of all the dates by month and year? Is there some possibility that I could get a sorted result of:

```
duedatemonth  | count 
January 2012  | 2
Feburary 2012 | 2
January 2013  | 1
March 2013    | 1
```

I know you can GROUP BY duedate, but that only groups those with the same month, day, and year instead of just month and year.

Would it be then possible to even further group it such that it factors in "assignment" to obtain a resulting table of

```
id | duedatemonth  | count 
1  | January 2012  | 2
3  | January 2012  | 2
2  | Feburary 2012 | 2
4  | Feburary 2012 | 2
5  | January 2013  | 1
6  | March 2013    | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(duedate,'%M %Y')  duedatemonth, COUNT(*) count
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY year(duedate), MONTH(duedate)
```

[**DEMO  HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9df1/7)

will output this:

```
   DUEDATEMONTH     COUNT
   January 2012     2
  February 2012     2
   January 2013     1
     March 2013     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string functions `YEAR` and `MONTH`.

```
SELECT YEAR(duedate), MONTH(duedate), COUNT(*)
FROM sparkles
GROUP BY YEAR(duedate), MONTH(duedate)
```

Use `MONTHNAME` or `DATE_FORMAT` to get the name of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(duedate, '%M %Y') duedatemonth, COUNT(1) `count`
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(duedate, '%M %Y')
```